# Ajax call always going in error part

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have demo in mvc where I want to fetch user details based on dropdown, i am using ajax for selectedindex changed event of dropdown to show userdetails in partial view, but ajax call is always going in error part..

```
Controller :-

  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usermodel = new UserModel();
        usermodel.listuser = GetUserData();
        usermodel.UserId = usermodel.listuser.First().UserId;
        usermodel.UserName = usermodel.listuser.First().UserName;
        usermodel.UserSalary = usermodel.listuser.First().UserSalary;

        return View(usermodel);
    }

    public PartialViewResult GetUserRecord(int UserId)
    {
        var userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.listuser = GetUserData();
        var user = userModel.listuser.Where(e => e.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault();

        userModel.UserId = user.UserId;
        userModel.UserName = user.UserName;
        userModel.UserSalary = user.UserSalary;

        return PartialView("_UserTestPartial.cshtml", userModel);
    }



    private List<UserModel> GetUserData()
    {
        var listuser = new List<UserModel>();
        var user1 = new UserModel();
        user1.UserId = 1;
        user1.UserName = "Abcd";
        user1.UserSalary = 25000;
        var user2 = new UserModel();
        user2.UserId = 2;
        user2.UserName = "bcde";
        user2.UserSalary = 35000;
        var user3 = new UserModel();
        user3.UserId = 1;
        user3.UserName = "cdef";
        user3.UserSalary = 45000;
        listuser.Add(user1);
        listuser.Add(user2);
        listuser.Add(user3);
        return listuser;
    }

Model:-
 public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public double UserSalary { get; set; }

    public List<UserModel> listuser { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable < SelectListItem > UserListItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(listuser, "UserId", "UserName");
        }
    }


}
```

Index View:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, Model.UserListItems, "---Select User---  ", new { Class = "ddlStyle", id = "ddlUser" })

<div id="partialDiv">
@Html.Partial("_UserTestPartial")
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlUser").on("change", function () {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/User/GetUserRecord?UserId=' + $(this).attr("value"),
            type: 'GET',
            data: " ",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#partialDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Partial View:-

```
@model Dropdowndemo.Models.UserModel

<fieldset>
<legend>UserModel</legend>
<div class="display-label">
    <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId) </strong>
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserId)
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName) </strong>
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>
<div class="display-label">
    <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserSalary) </strong>
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserSalary)
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Try changing your request to `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`

Comment: what error it throwing? check your console might be you need to replace `$(this).attr('value')`to `$(this).val()`

Comment: tried after changing to $(this).val()...still it is always going in error part

Comment: your content type must be `contentType: text/html` as you are returning partial view

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the **data: " "**, attribute from ajax, if you're not passing any in it.

Comment: I used $("#ddlUser option:selected").val() instead of $(this).attr('value') and now it is working fine...thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Index remove

@Html.Partial("_UserTestPartial")

This will throw error since you are not passing any model to the partial view in this way.

As you were binding the partial view via ajax call to #partialDiv it will work fine